# flutter provider error : Could not find the correct provider above this widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I get a error when trying to navigate to the receiptDetailScreen page in my app.
My app has the following structure :

```
-main (MaterialApp, Provider)
-homeScreen
-receiptListSCreen
-receiptDetailScreen
```

I can navigate from the homescreen to the receiptListScreen.  But when i try to go to the receiptDetailScreen from there i get the Error:

Could not find the correct Provider above this ReceiptDetailScreen Widget

My Main.dart looks like :

```
Widget build(BuildContext maincontext) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: GreatPlaces()),
        //.....
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          canvasColor: Color(0xFF363567),
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Home(),
        routes: {
          SettingsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => SettingsScreen(),
          ImageInputScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ImageInputScreen(),
          AddReceiptScreen.routeName: (ctx) => AddReceiptScreen(),
          ReceiptListScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ReceiptListScreen(),
          ReceiptDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ReceiptDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

my homepage looks like :

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF363567),
        body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 12,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            // height: 300,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.60,
                            child: buildGrid(context),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 12,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
        )
    );
  }

  Widget buildGrid(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      childAspectRatio: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60 / 2) / 300,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildTile(
          context,
          0,
          "New receipt",
          null,
          Icons.add,
          "1,456 items",
          Colors.orange,
          Colors.orange[50],
          '/add-receipt',
        ),
        buildTile(
          context,
          1,
          "Show list",
          null,
          Icons.list,
          "658 items",
          Colors.blue,
          Colors.blue[50],
          '/receipts-list',
        ),
        buildTile(
          context,
          2,
          "settings",
          null,
          Icons.settings,
          "217 items",
          Colors.purple,
          Colors.purple[50],
          'routename',
        ),
        buildTile(
          context,
          3,
          "About",
          null,
          Icons.info,
          "24 items",
          Colors.red,
          Colors.red[50],
          'routename',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  int _selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget buildTile(
      BuildContext context,
      int index,
      String heading,
      Image image,
      IconData icon,
      String itemCount,
      Color color,
      Color backgroundColor,
      String route) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: index == 0 || index == 2 || index == 4 ? 12 : 5,
          top: 0,
          right: index == 1 || index == 3 || index == 5 ? 12 : 5,
          bottom: 10),

      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(route);
          });
          print("tapped");
        },
        child: Card(
            elevation: 3,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    color: _selectedIndex == index && color != null
                        ? color
                        : Color(0xFF3D416E)),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            color: Color(0xFF3D416E),
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 43,
                      height: 43,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFF3D416E),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      icon,
                      color: color,
                    ),
                    index != 1
                        ? SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          )
                        : SizedBox(
                            height: 0,
                          ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  heading,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Text(
                  itemCount,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                )
              ],
            ))),
      ),
//      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the receiptListScreen looks like :

```
class ReceiptListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/receipts-list';

  void selectReceipt(BuildContext ctx, String id) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(ReceiptDetailScreen.routeName,
        arguments: {'id': id, });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF363567),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Receipts'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddReceiptScreen.routeName);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAndSetReceipts(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.waiting
            ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
            : Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
            child: Center(
              child: const Text('Got No Receipts yet, start adding?!'),
            ),
            builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) => greatPlaces.items.length <= 0
                ? ch
                : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: greatPlaces.items.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: FileImage(greatPlaces.items[i].image),
                  ),
                  title: Text(greatPlaces.items[i].title,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: () {
                    selectReceipt(context,greatPlaces.items[i].id );
                   
                  },
                ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and finally the receiptDetailScreen looks like :

```
class ReceiptDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static const routeName = '/receipt-details';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final id = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final selectedReceipt = Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false).findById(id);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(selectedReceipt.title),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(height: 250, width: double.infinity,
          child: Image.file(
            selectedReceipt.image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
            ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Text(selectedReceipt.purchaseDate),
          SizedBox(height :10),
          Text(selectedReceipt.warrantyPeriod),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems as if the context of the materialapp doesnt get through to the receiptdetailsceen but i cant figure out where i go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. a fresh install of android studio and the problem dissapeared